# How to parse a string and get the value after "=" character

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, substring

So I have string that should contains "Object.Name" once in a row , if I see it ,I have to get the value after "=" character. If doesn't match it anywhere in the string i should move hardcoded value.

Here is example of the string:

```
Object.Name=ASDD||Product.Name=DSA
Product.Name=QWE||Object.Name=WSXS
Storage.Name=12345||Object.Name=WERR||Product.Name=QAZ
```

I know that I should use case for that but doesn't know how to proceed the string

```sql
case
    when (match the string ) then (value after the "=")
    else (hardcoded value)
end
```

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: @Stu ahh okay , i know I have to use SUBSTRING function but doesn't really make it to work.

Comment: Function names, syntax and usage are RDBMS-specific.

Comment: @Stu ahh okay i am new to sql didn't know there is difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN start_pos = 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE SUBSTR(
              '||' || value || '||',
              start_pos + LENGTH('||Object.Name='),
              end_pos - start_pos - LENGTH('||Object.Name=')
            )
       END AS object_name
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(
           '||' || value || '||',
           '||Object.Name='
         ) AS start_pos,
         INSTR(
           '||' || value || '||',
           '||',
           INSTR('||' || value || '||', '||Object.Name=')+LENGTH('||Object.Name=')
         ) AS end_pos
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Object.Name=ASDD||Product.Name=DSA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Product.Name=QWE||Object.Name=WSXS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Storage.Name=12345||Object.Name=WERR||Product.Name=QAZ' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | OBJECT_NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | Object.Name=ASDD||Product.Name=DSA | ASDD |
> | Product.Name=QWE||Object.Name=WSXS | WSXS |
> | Storage.Name=12345||Object.Name=WERR||Product.Name=QAZ | WERR |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=52b97de1079755e79202706d8ec3c264)*

---

Since you changed the tags, in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN start_pos = 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE SUBSTRING(
              CONCAT('||', value, '||'),
              start_pos + LENGTH('||Object.Name='),
              end_pos - start_pos - LENGTH('||Object.Name=')
            )
       END AS object_name
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         LOCATE(
           '||Object.Name=',
           CONCAT('||', value, '||')
         ) AS start_pos,
         LOCATE(
           '||',
           CONCAT('||', value, '||'),
           LOCATE('||Object.Name=', CONCAT('||', value, '||'))
             + LENGTH('||Object.Name=')
         ) AS end_pos
  FROM   table_name
) t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c09104d83d64be7f5c9956826007ee06)*